# "Program log: Instruction: GetAccountDataSize", "Program log: Error: IncorrectProgramId", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA

Tags: token, spl-token-program, associated-token-program

Based on reading [https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/program/src/instruction.rs#L426][1]

It looks like the Token program does in fact have GetAccountDataSize so I am wondering why the fallowing code

```
def compile_transaction(owner_wallet: Keypair, instructions: list, latest_blockhash) -> VersionedTransaction:
    """
    compiles a simple msg and returns a versioned transaction
    """

    msg = MessageV0.try_compile(
        payer=owner_wallet.pubkey(),
        instructions=instructions,
        address_lookup_table_accounts=[],
        recent_blockhash=latest_blockhash
    )

    return VersionedTransaction(message=msg, keypairs=[owner_wallet])


def create_token_account(owner_wallet_path: str, mint_keypair_path: str):
    client = Client(CLIENT_ADDRESS)
    response = client.get_latest_blockhash()
    latest_blockhash = response.value.blockhash

    owner_wallet = get_keypair_from_file(owner_wallet_path)
    mint_keypair = get_keypair_from_file(mint_keypair_path)
    mint_pubkey = mint_keypair.pubkey()
    associated_token_address = get_associated_token_address(
        owner=owner_wallet.pubkey(),
        mint=mint_pubkey
    )
    print(f'associated_token_address: {associated_token_address}')
    # Check if the token account already exists
    account_info = client.get_account_info(associated_token_address)
    if account_info.value is not None:
        raise ValueError(f'Token account {associated_token_address} already exists')
    else:
        create_token_account_instruction = create_associated_token_account(owner_wallet.pubkey(), owner_wallet.pubkey(), mint_pubkey)

    # Create the InitializeAccount instruction
    initialize_account_instruction = initialize_account(
        InitializeAccountParams(
            account=associated_token_address,
            mint=mint_pubkey,
            owner=owner_wallet.pubkey(),
            program_id=TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
        )
    )
    print(f'The token program is {TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID}')
    print(f'The associated token program is {ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID}')
    create_account_txn = compile_transaction(owner_wallet, [create_token_account_instruction, initialize_account_instruction], latest_blockhash)
    client.send_transaction(create_account_txn)
    print(f'Created token account {associated_token_address} for {owner_wallet.pubkey()}')
    write_associated_token_account_to_file(associated_token_address, owner_wallet_path)
    return associated_token_address
```

Generates the fallowing error message

```
solana.rpc.core.RPCException: SendTransactionPreflightFailureMessage { message: "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: incorrect program id for instruction", data: RpcSimulateTransactionResult(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(InstructionError(0, IncorrectProgramId)), logs: Some(["Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [1]", "Program log: Create", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]", "Program log: Instruction: GetAccountDataSize", "Program log: Error: IncorrectProgramId", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 884 of 394486 compute units", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: incorrect program id for instruction", "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 6398 of 400000 compute units", "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL failed: incorrect program id for instruction"]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(0), return_data: None }) }
```

This is on devnet

Answer (score 0):

If you're running into that error during `GetAccountDataSize`, I'm almost 100% sure it's this line: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/c94eeec63bdada46453eb46d0e7add4c504b1799/token/program/src/processor.rs#L790

This means that the mint hasn't been initialized yet, or at the very least, that it isn't assigned to the token program. Be sure to create and initialize the mint before creating the associated token account.